# React MUI: Persistent + Responsive drawer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am trying to connect React Material UI: Persistent + Responsive drawer so that mobile will be Responsive drawer and above mobile will be Persistent.

I found a code that almost works but I do not have a second button in it that Toggles the Persistent.

Can anyone help me add it because I'm trying to do it?

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import { mailFolderListItems, otherMailFolderListItems } from './tileData';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    height: 430,
    zIndex: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%',
  },
  appBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    },
  },
  navIconHide: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      position: 'relative',
    },
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
  },
});

class ResponsiveDrawer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    mobileOpen: false,
  };

  handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ mobileOpen: !state.mobileOpen }));
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, theme } = this.props;

    const drawer = (
      <div>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <Divider />
        <List>{mailFolderListItems}</List>
        <Divider />
        <List>{otherMailFolderListItems}</List>
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="Open drawer"
              onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
              className={classes.navIconHide}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
              Responsive drawer
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Hidden mdUp>
          <Drawer
            variant="temporary"
            anchor={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'right' : 'left'}
            open={this.state.mobileOpen}
            onClose={this.handleDrawerToggle}
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
            ModalProps={{
              keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
            }}
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden smDown implementation="css">
          <Drawer
            variant="permanent"
            open
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
        <main className={classes.content}>
          <div className={classes.toolbar} />
          <Typography noWrap>{'You think water moves fast? You should see ice.'}</Typography>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ResponsiveDrawer.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(ResponsiveDrawer);
```

Comment: What you actually want to do? add your code please or create demo

Comment: You can try using useMediaQuery to replace the Hidden part for mobile view of the drawer , and using only one state to manage the toggle of the drawer.

Answer (score 0):

I merge two responsive and Persistent like follow but maybe we have a better solution but please look at following codes

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
    },
    drawer: {
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            width: drawerWidth,
            flexShrink: 0,
        },
    },
    hide: {
        display: 'none',
    },
    drawerPersistent: {
        width: drawerWidth,
        flexShrink: 0,
    },
    appBar: {
        marginLeft: drawerWidth,
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
        },
    },
    appBarPersistent: {
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
    },
    appBarShiftPersistent: {
        width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
        marginLeft: drawerWidth,
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: 20,
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            display: 'none',
        },
    },
    menuButtonPersistent: {
        marginLeft: 12,
        marginRight: 20,
    },
    toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
    drawerPaper: {
        width: drawerWidth,
    },
    content: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    },
    drawerHeaderPersistent: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: '0 8px',
        ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    },
    contentPersistent: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
        transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
        marginLeft: -drawerWidth,
    },
    contentShiftPersistent: {
        transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
        marginLeft: 0,
    },
});

class ResponsiveDrawer extends React.Component {
    state = {
        open: true,
        mobileOpen: false,
        children: this.props.routes.children
    };

    handleDrawerToggle = () => {
        this.setState(state => ({ mobileOpen: !state.mobileOpen }));
    };
    handleDrawerOpen = () => {
        this.setState({ open: true });
    };

    handleDrawerClose = () => {
        this.setState({ open: false });
    };

    render() {
        const { classes, theme } = this.props;
        const { open } = this.state;

        const drawer = (
            <div dir="rtl">
                <div className={classes.toolbar} />
                <Divider />
                <List>
                    {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
                        <ListItem button key={text}>
                            <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary={text} />
                        </ListItem>
                    ))}
                </List>
                <Divider />
                <List>
                    {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
                        <ListItem button key={text}>
                            <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary={text} />
                        </ListItem>
                    ))}
                </List>
            </div>
        );

        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <CssBaseline />

                {/* The implementation can be swapped with js to avoid SEO duplication of links. */}
                <Hidden smUp implementation="css">
                    <nav className={classes.drawer}>
                        <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
                            <Toolbar>
                                <IconButton
                                    color="inherit"
                                    aria-label="Open drawer"
                                    onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
                                    className={classes.menuButton}
                                >
                                    <MenuIcon />
                                </IconButton>
                                <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
                                    Responsive drawer
                                </Typography>
                            </Toolbar>
                        </AppBar>


                        <Drawer
                            container={this.props.container}
                            variant="temporary"
                            anchor={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'left' : 'right'}
                            open={this.state.mobileOpen}
                            onClose={this.handleDrawerToggle}
                            classes={{
                                paper: classes.drawerPaper,
                            }}
                        >
                            {drawer}
                        </Drawer>
                    </nav>
                    <main className={classes.content}>
                        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
                        {this.state.children}
                    </main>
                </Hidden>
                <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
                    <nav className={classes.drawerPersistent}>
                        <AppBar
                            position="fixed"
                            className={classNames(classes.appBarPersistent, {
                                [classes.appBarShiftPersistent]: open,
                            })}
                        >
                            <Toolbar disableGutters={!open}>
                                <IconButton
                                    color="inherit"
                                    aria-label="Open drawer"
                                    onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen}
                                    className={classNames(classes.menuButtonPersistent, open && classes.hide)}
                                >
                                    <MenuIcon />
                                </IconButton>

                                <Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'white' }} className={classNames(open && classes.hide)}>
                                    <img src="/images/Music-PNG-Photos.png" alt="logo" style={{ width: '120px', height: '70px' }} />

                                </Link>

                            </Toolbar>
                        </AppBar>
                        <Drawer
                            className={classes.drawerHeaderPersistent}
                            variant="persistent"
                            anchor="left"
                            open={open}
                            classes={{
                                paper: classes.drawerPaper,
                            }}
                        >
                            <div className={classes.drawerHeaderPersistent}>


                                <Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'white' }}>
                                    <img src="/images/Music-PNG-Photos.png" alt="logo" style={{ width: '120px', height: '70px' }} />
                                </Link>
                                <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}>
                                    {theme.direction === 'ltr' ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : <ChevronRightIcon />}
                                </IconButton>


                            </div>
                            {drawer}
                        </Drawer>
                    </nav>
                    <main
                        className={classNames(classes.contentPersistent, {
                            [classes.contentShiftPersistent]: open,
                        })}
                    >
                        <div className={classes.drawerHeaderPersistent} />
                        {this.state.children}
                    </main>
                </Hidden>


            </div >
        );
    }
}

ResponsiveDrawer.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    // Injected by the documentation to work in an iframe.
    // You won't need it on your project.
    container: PropTypes.object,
    theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(ResponsiveDrawer);
```